# R mapview choose color of polygon based on color code in column

Tags: r, colors, r-mapview

I got polygon spatial data (could be points too) with a column specifying the color in hex. Could be something like:

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("gold1", "gold3"))
clrs <- colfunc(6)
names(clrs) <- c(0:5)

breweries$clrs <- clrs[match(breweries$number.seasonal.beers,names(clrs))]
```

Now I want mapview to set these colors as colors in the map to the according point (or polygon in my real data).
I tried `zcol` and `col.regions` but it does not seem to work like this. Do you have any suggestions?